# Using the Like operator with two fields

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

How do I use the `Like` operator to join two unidentical tables as below? My main problem is on how to compare the `PO` filed on `tbl2` to the `EditNo` on `tbl1` field. Please see sample tables and expected results below:

**tbl1:**

```
         EditNo                     PriceAfter    Status 

     L914; PO2234                    22.00         Yes                       

     l910; po*2240                    38.00         No

Inv Date23/01/21; L919; PO2110       35.29         Waiting
```

**tbl2:**

```
         PO          PriceBefore 

        2234        20.00

        2235        00.00                      

        2240        32.00

        2110        35.00
```

**Expected:**

```
         PO           Status    PriceBefore  PriceAfter  

         2234         Yes       20.00        22.00

         2235         No        00.00        0.00               

         2240         No        32.00        28.00

         2110         Waiting   35.00        35.29
```

**Query:**

`SELECT * FROM tbl2  INNER JOIN  tbl1 ON tbl2.PONo LIKE EditNo.PO;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need wildcards:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl2 INNER JOIN
     tbl1
     ON tbl1.EditNo LIKE "*" & tbl2.PONo;
```

The '*' means any character(s).

Comment: I must apologise for a typo earlier `tbl1` field `EditNo` has a value `po*2240` would the `*` in the field be a problem?

Comment: @WKI . . . No.  It is not in the pattern being compared.

Comment: in this case should `tbl1.EditNo LIKE "*" & tbl2.PONo & "*"` return the row with value `LC; PO1234*; *PO1234*; C5; *PO1234; L` in the `EditNo` field

Comment: @WKI . . . In all your examples, the number is at the end, which is why there is no wildcard there.  Of course, you can adapt the answer for other situations as well.